# What is the best way to upload and store pictures on the site?

Tags: php, file-upload

I have no idea how the big websites save the pictures on their servers. Could any one tell me how do they save the pictures that are uploaded by the users in their database?

I was thinking, maybe they would just save the file(the picture) in some path and just save that path in the databse is that right?

But I want to do it this way. Is this right? For example, a website named `www.photos.com`.  When a user uploads a picture I would create a folder of the user name and save those pictures in that folder.

I believe we can create a directory using `php file concepts`.  So when a new user uploads his picture or file, I want to create a directory with his name.

Example: if user name is john, I would create a directory like this on photos.com `www.photos.com/john/` and then save all his pictures to this directory when he uploads a picture.  Is this the right way to do this?

I have no one here that has good knowledge of saving the files to servers so please let me know how to do this? I want to do it the correct and secure way.

Comment: @AdrianCornish Could you tell me what you mean by what have you tried? Im not asking you to write a code for me ,i just want the algorithm or the process the most people follow so that I could go ahead if i know what to do

Comment: Again what have you tried? You can store a path to the file, you can store the binary data in the database. What is your actual question?

Comment: Your question is badly phrased - you are asking how to upload pictures. Not how to store pictures upload to your site. Also what are you doing to protect users against upload malicious code, images with hidden payloads, stopping people just grabbing all your images from a index'able url

Comment: the word 'database' has a special meaning. and you misled every one tried to answer your question. however, that's their bad as they didn't read the question actually

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: @niko don't understand why you accepted an answer that was, clearly, mislead by your first line of questioning and then not updated to answer what you where actually asking for...

Comment: @Frankie sorry i dont know but i accepted your answer and thanks for letting me know that well i appreciated your help with the answer Thanks frankie

Answer (score 251, accepted):

All big websites **don't save pictures to the database**; they store them on the disk. They save a reference to the picture's position in a table and then link from there.

Why? Performance.

Pulling heavy content from a database is a huge performance bottleneck. And databases don't scale horizontally that well, so it would mean an even bigger problem. All big sites use static content farms to deal with static content such as images. Those are servers that won't care less about your identity.

How do they keep the pictures really private, you might ask? They don't.

The picture's link is, in itself, the address and the password. Let's take Facebook, for example. If I store a private picture on my account, you should not be able to open it. But, as long as you have the correct address, you can.

**[This picture is private](https://scontent-a-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/t1.0-9/10400121_87110566301_7482172_n.jpg).** Notice the filename
`10400121_87110566301_7482172_n.jpg`
*(Facebook changes the URL from time to time, so the link may be broken)*

It's non-sequential. The only way to get the picture is to know its address.
Based on a previous user photo, you can't guess the next one.
It has a huge entropy, so even if you start taking random wild guesses, you'll have an extensive amount of failures, and if you do get to a picture, you won't be able to, from there, realize the owner's identity, which, in itself, is protection in anonymity.

**Edit (why you should not store images in a "username" folder):**
After your edit, it became clear that you do intend to put files on disk and not on the database. This edit covers the new scenario.

Even though your logic (create a folder per user) seems more organized, it creates problems when you start having many users and many pictures. Imagine that your servers have 1T disk space. And let's also imagine that 1T is more or less accurate with the load the server can handle.

Now you have 11 users. Assume they start uploading at the same time, and each will upload more than 100GB of files. When they reach 91GB each, the server is full, and you must start storing images on a different server. If that user/folder structure is followed, you would have to select one of the users and migrate all of his data to a different server. Also, it makes a hard limit on a user who can't upload more than 1T in files.

**Should I store all files in the same folder, then?**
No, big sites generally store files in sequential folders (/000001/, /000002/, etc.) having an x defined number of files per folder. This is mainly for file-system performance issues.

**2023 edit, the extra check:**
Nowadays, most large companies also check if the user is allowed the resource/image before serving it. But the logic stays mostly the same. Apart from what's described above, before serving the resource, you do a double check on the DB to see if the user is allowed.

More on [**how many files in a directory is too many?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many)

Comment: BRILLIANT explanation. Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Thank you Frankie, that's indeed very clear. But there is another way which should me more interesting: store the pictures on a specific picture storage provider.

Comment: @Fred absolutely true. This answer is specifically designed to set the correct mindset on someone who has no idea on how things work. As soon you start hosting a couple of million pictures on your site you'll probably wanna split the problem and/or outsource hosting those assets. The mindset, though, stays the same. On the database you only reference image location. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: is the a framwork/tool/implementation of dealing with this that we can use either off the shelf or at least understand how to do it ourselves? (AKA what details to store in the DB, how to number the folders and files, etc)

Comment: @Daniel, I've got no idea if there is an off the shelf library, one thing I know for certain is that most "big websites", if not all, have custom solutions. Regarding numbering the files, you'll want something that minimizes collisions. If you were numbering sequentially, multiple servers would opt for the same "key". You'll want the naming to be something like described above; a random hash.

Answer (score 9):

It is usually a bad idea to store images in your database (if your site is popular). Database is, traditionally, one of main bottlenecks in most any application out there. No need to load it more than necessary. If images are in the filesystem, many http servers ([nginx](http://nginx.org), for example) will serve them most efficiently.

The biggest social network in Russia, [Vkontakte](http://vk.com) does exactly this: store images in the filesystem.

Another big social network implemented a sophisticated scalable blob storage. But it's not available to the public, AFAIK.

Summary of this answer: don't store blobs in the database.

Answer (score 4):

> is this the right way to do

Yes.
The only thing I'd suggest to use not name but id.
`www.photos.com/albums/1234/` would be okay for starter.

Answer (score 3):

Image management may best be achieved by physically uploading images to the server and then recording file location and image details in a database. Subsequently, a Search Form could be configured to permit the user to do a text search, part number search, or other queries. A PHP script could be written to produce a valid HTML image tag based on data found in the table.

uploading images into a MySQL™ BLOB field is such a bad idea such image data is generally problematic if the images are much larger than thumbnails. If the images are large, you can end up having to copy/paste one SQL INSERT statement at a time (into phpMyAdmin). If the images are large and the SQL INSERT statement is broken into two lines by your text editor, you'll never be able to restore the image.